# Canvas dimensions cause a vertical scroll bar to appear

Tags: html, css, canvas

On this page it shows a vertical scroll bar. Why ? If I replace the 'canvas' element with a 'div' element all works fine.
  To make the scroll go away I can change the :

height: calc(100% - 80px);

to :

height: calc(100% - 85px);

But this is not right because I loss space on the bottom of the page.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
    <style>
        html {
            padding: 0px;
            border: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        body {
            padding: 0px;
            border: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background: #00FFFF;
        }

        .top {
            padding: 0px;
            border: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            background-color: #FF0000;
            width: 100%;
            height: 80px;
        }

        .cv {
            padding: 0px;
            border: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            background-color: #00FF00;
            width: 100%;
            height: calc(100% - 80px);
            border-image-width: 0px;       
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="top">
    </div>

    <canvas class="cv">
    </canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This scroll is because of `canvas` as it is by default an `inline` element.

Add `overflow: hidden` to `body`

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

OR you can remove extra white space of canvas by one of two ways:

1. `.cv {display: block;}`
2. `.cv {vertical-align: top;}`

```css
html {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #00FFFF;
}

.top {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

.cv {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  border-image-width: 0px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
</div>

<canvas class="cv">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
   .cv {
      display: block;    /* ADD ME!!!! */
```

because canvas is by default an inline element